# How to make hover gradient on a div element like on Wella.com?

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover, gradient

I need to make a gradient hover effect on a div element (example: http://www.wella.com/professional/en-UK/home )

How can I do it? Is it better to use jQuery or css? I was trying to use Chrome developer tools to find out, but in vain. Please, can someone help me with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** As commented you wanted to have a bg-image with the gradient effect on top. So using :hover you can actually target a different class, so it would go like this:

Check the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/5knqpv1x/1/)

Updated CSS:

```
.hoverable {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50vh;
  background-image: url('http://media.wella.com/professional/m/_master/homepage/Home%20Gallery%20Item/for-all-latest-news_d.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
}

.hoverable:hover .content {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(200, 0, 60, 0) 0%, rgba(200, 0, 60, 0.5) 100%);
}
```

---

CSS is probably your best choice, you can catch the :hover event on your css to apply the desired gradient over the `div` you intend.

Check [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucaslazaro/5knqpv1x/) for more information, but it goes like this:

```css
.hoverable {
  width: 80%;
  height: 50vh;
}
.hoverable:hover {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(200, 0, 60, 0) 0%, rgba(200, 0, 60, 0.5) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(200, 0, 60, 0) 0%, rgba(200, 0, 60, 0.5) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(200, 0, 60, 0) 0%, rgba(200, 0, 60, 0.5) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(200, 0, 60, 0) 0%, rgba(200, 0, 60, 0.5) 100%);
}
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="hoverable">

  <div class="content">
    Really nice in here
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!
Cheers

Comment: Thanks, but what if I use  background-image inside content class? Hover effect doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @dinodino11 Oh! I get it, I've updated the answer to match your requirements, but you'd simply target a inside div with the `:hover` effect. Let me know if I can be of any more help.

Answer (score 0):

That's a great question. Here's a theoretical answer first and then a specific answer to your question.
Usually you want to keep design changes in CSS. While keeping Javascript (jQuery is a javascript library) focusing on functionality.

Now to more specifically address that hover effect, I'm not sure how they did it on the website you referenced, but if you're simply toggling a gradient overlay for a div, then I would suggest just using the :hover CSS pseudo selector. It is simple, clean, and it will work on all of these browsers http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2

Your CSS would look like this

```
div:hover {
    background: linear-gradient( ... ); //Add all vendor prefixes
    transition 3s; //Add all vendor prefixes
}
```

Have a great day!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Andrew!